# Add $ or € sign to an Eval value

Tags: .net, eval

I would like to display a monetary value on my page, I'm using a label with as text `Text='<%#Eval("Price")%>'`.

But how can you add € or $ to it? So you get `€ 50,00 or $ 50,00` instead of `50,00`?

Thank you for your help

Comment: An integer? That not suitable for any monetary value. You should consider using the Decimal type.

Comment: whoops my bad, it is indeed a decimal(8,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}") %>
```

Comment: formatType: System.String, A .NET Framework format string (like those used by String.Format) that converts the Object instance returned by the data-binding expression to a String object. 
ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal myPrice = 50.20;
Console.WriteLine(myPrice.ToString("C")); // uses the current culture.
```

Comment: not really what I'm looking for, I just need to be able to add `€ or $` to the text value. But thanks for your code though.